# Making a Scatterplot in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

My data plot is called cba first is the instructions and here is my code. I am struggling with Problem 3 Part B
[image: Instructions]

```
#PART A 
clean_df = subset(df, !is.na(cba$SAT_math))
```

```
#PART B  
plot(clean_df,cba$SAT_verbal, xlab="Math SAT Score", main="Relationship Between Math and Verbal SAT Scores", ylab= "Verbal SAT Score")
```

> Error in plot.default(...): formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments

Comment: Provide the data in `dput()` format. Do not put your codes as images. Visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: ```{r}
#PART A
clean_df = subset(df, !is.na(cba$SAT_math))
```

```{r}
#PART B

plot(clean_df,cba$SAT_verbal, xlab="Math SAT Score", main="Relationship Between Math and Verbal SAT Scores", ylab= "Verbal SAT Score")

```

Comment: This time I have helped you out by editing the question. Please edit your question by providing the data in `dput()` format.

Comment: it won't let me because the data is too big

Comment: I am using your code with `iris` data like `plot(iris$Petal.Length,iris$Sepal.Length, xlab="Math SAT Score", main="Relationship Between Math and Verbal SAT Scores", ylab= "Verbal SAT Score")` and it is working fine. Show the output of `str(clean_df)`.

Comment: You're doing `plot(x=clean_df, y=cba$SAT_verbal)` which probably doesn't make much sense. Read help page by typing `?plot`.